# catalog_product_entity_media_gallery in mysql is missing

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql

I'm using magento 1.8, 
I want to import products with a csv file. the file is okay, but i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DE)
```

I checked this in phpmyadmin and the table 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' is missing. what can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Using one of your database backups, I would find out when that table went missing. Then copy that table from your backup to your production database.

Tables just don't go ahead and disappear, most likely someone delete it (accidentally or not).

Comment: well, many thanks for your help. the problem is, i've assumed the shop as new as new employee and the old technical didn't do a backup with this table :/

Comment: If that is the case, I would suggest creating a clean copy of Magento and either porting all the information from the existing database over to the clean one, or you take that table from the clean db and copy it over to your existing database.